# Do Transaction Fees Count Towards Roth IRA Contribution Limit?

Tags: united-states, taxes, roth-ira

I'm using Interactive Brokers. I noticed that IBKR charges a transaction fee for the purchase of some funds. Does that transaction fee count toward the Roth IRA contribution limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - the money you put in the IRA counts as contributions. Fees charged within the IRA, as well as gains and dividends, do not count.

For example, If you put the maximum amount ($7,000 for 2024) into a Roth IRA, and your trades cost $10 in transaction fees, you will end up with $6,990 in investments after fees.